# li items collapsing vertically when using bookmark

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm making this website:

http://frankkluytmans.nl/testsite/

And making a list view in which i'm using the wookmark jquery plugin to make the list items align proper vertically. Now the list items are collapsing vertically (see link). What can I do to solve this?

CSS:

```
#content ol {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    margin-left: -2%;

    list-style-type: none;
}

#content ol li {
    display: block;
    width: 18%;
    height: auto;
    margin-left: 2%;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding: 3px;

    background: white;
    float: left;    
}

#content ol li img {
    width: 100%;
    border: none;   
}
```

JS:

```
$('#content ol li').wookmark({
     container: $('#content ol'),
     offset: 20
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to work out a solution on my own. Turns out webkit browsers need the images to be loaded first to be able to calculate the correct height for the list elements.

I tweaked my JS to this:

```
 $("img").load(function() {
        $('#content ol li').wookmark({
            container: $('#content ol'),
            offset: 15
        });
    });
```